# List operation for nested list

Tags: python, list, iterable-unpacking

I have the following list:

```
list = [(1,info1),(2,info2),(3,info3)...]
```

each info is consisted of a list of tuples

```
info1 = [(a1,b1,c1),(a1',b1',c1'),(a1",b1",c1")...]
```

for each element in `list`, i want to have the following:

```
otherlist = [(1,(a1,b1,c1)),(1,(a1',b1',c1')),(1,(a1",b1",c1"))...]
```

that is: the index in front of `info` to be placed in front of each tuple of info

I think this is doable, but I am not able to achieve this with simple list comprehension

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Don't name a list `list`, that masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
otherlist = [(x[0],y) for x in first_list for y in x[1]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a *nested* list comprehension:

```
otherlist = [[(L[0], t) for t in L[1]] for L in lst]
```

so for each element `L` in `lst`, we create a new list with tuples containing `(L[0], elements of L[1])`.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [(1, [('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ("a1'", "b1'", "c1'"), ('a1"', 'b1"', 'c1"')]), (2, [('a3', 'b3', 'c3'), ("a3'", "b3'", "c3'"), ('a3"', 'b3"', 'c3"')]), (3, [('a3', 'b3', 'c3'), ("a3'", "b3'", "c3'"), ('a3"', 'b3"', 'c3"')])]
>>> [[(L[0], t) for t in L[1]] for L in lst]
[[(1, ('a1', 'b1', 'c1')), (1, ("a1'", "b1'", "c1'")), (1, ('a1"', 'b1"', 'c1"'))], [(2, ('a3', 'b3', 'c3')), (2, ("a3'", "b3'", "c3'")), (2, ('a3"', 'b3"', 'c3"'))], [(3, ('a3', 'b3', 'c3')), (3, ("a3'", "b3'", "c3'")), (3, ('a3"', 'b3"', 'c3"'))]]
```

Comment: more clear than mine i think(+1) ...but i think you need to chain it at the end to match his expected

Comment: No, I think I have it right; `for each element in list, i want to have the following`. I don't think it should be chained.

Comment: ahhh you maybe right its not totally clear ... but trivial to transform if needed

Comment: @MartijnPieters which one of the 'for' conditions does the compiler evaluate first? or it evaluates both in "parallel"?

Comment: It evaluates the right-hand loop first; the nested list comprehension is executed in full for each iteration of that outer loop.

Comment: interestingly enough the compiler works fine with the example given by @JoranBeasley and gives error with the one by Martin

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne: What error do you get then? I have had no problems running it.